# Generalized Jacobi-Madden equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

The [Jacobi-Madden equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Madden_equation)
$ a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4 = (a+b+c+d)^4 $
has an infinitude of integer solutions with all variables non-zero.

Is it known if the same is true for the general equation $ \sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i^n = (\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i)^n$ ?

I tried to look for some references, but found nothing.

Comment: You should add that we are looking for integer solutions. For $n=2$ we have $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2$, which means $2ab=0$. Since $ab\neq 0$, we have no integer solution at all.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sure, I edit!

Comment: For $n$ odd there are trivial solutions, e.g., $a^5+(-a)^5+a^5+(-a)^5+a^5=(a+-a+a+-a+a)^5$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a similar question I answered back in 2014. See the [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/682666/4781) "*Integer Solutions of $x^3+y^3+z^3 = (x+y+z)^3.\,$* In summary,

---

**I. 4th powers**

There are *infinitely* many solutions to,

$$a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4=(a+b+c+d)^4$$

given by the Jacobi-Madden equation (2008).

---

**II. 5th powers**

There are also *infinitely* many solutions to,

$$a^5+b^5+c^5+d^5+e^5=(a+b+c+d+e)^5$$

given by Lander (1968). See "*Geometric Aspects of Diophantine equations involving Equal Sums of Like Powers*".

Note: Choudhry, Wroblewski, and others would also give more examples.

---

**III. 6th powers**

In Meyrignac's database http://euler.free.fr/database.txt, there are exactly 177+1 = 178 solutions to,

$$x_1^6+x_2^6+x_3^6+x_4^6+x_5^6+x_6^6+x_7^6 = z^6$$

mostly found between 2009 to 2012. Peter Ansell and others found many of these (6,1,7) and the aim was to find a (6,1,6). Ansell discovered **four** with the additional property,

$$x_1^6+x_2^6+x_3^6+\dots+x_7^6 = (x_1+x_2+x_3+\dots+x_7)^6$$

But he may have tested only his solutions, so there could be more.

---

**IV. 7th powers**

Choudhry and Wroblewski gave more than 20 solutions to the (7,1,7) that is also,

$$x_1^7+x_2^7+x_3^7+\dots+x_7^7 = (x_1+x_2+x_3+\dots+x_7)^7$$

See this [MO link](https://mathoverflow.net/q/191932/12905).

---

**V. 8th powers**

There is a (8,1,8) and a (8,1,9), but only the (8,1,10) satisfies,

$$x_1^8+x_2^8+x_3^8+\dots+x_{10}^8\, = \,(x_1+x_2+x_3+\dots+x_{10})^8$$

with $x_i$ as $(6, 16, 34, 58, 66, 142, 152, 171, -184, -226)$.

---

**VI. 9th powers**

There are many solutions to (9,1,9) but Wroblewski found the only one that is also,

$$x_1^9+x_2^9+x_3^9+\dots+x_9^9 = (x_1+x_2+x_3+\dots+x_9)^9$$

with $x_i$ as $(-100, -187, -429, -603, -621, 51, 253, 412, 600)$.

Note: Bremner and Delorme (*"On Equal Sums of Ninth Powers"*) found *infinitely* many to,

$$x_1^9+x_2^9+x_3^9+\dots+x_{11}^9 = (x_1+x_2+x_3+\dots+x_{11})^9$$

---

**VII. 10th powers**

1. A similar result uses a (10,1,12) by Wroblewski,

$$x_1^{10}+x_2^{10}+x_3^{10}+\dots+x_{12}^{10} = 2^{10}(x_1+x_2+x_3+\dots+x_{12})^{10}$$

The $x_i$ are $(-62, -115, 172, 245, -295, -533, 689, 927, 1011, -1234, -1603, 1684).$

2. Another uses a (10,1,13) by S. Chase,

$$x_1^{10}+x_2^{10}+x_3^{10}+\dots+x_{13}^{10} = (x_1+x_2+x_3+\dots+x_{13})^{10}$$

The $x_i$ are $(-187, -179, -128, -59, -13, -6, 49, 57, 73, 85, 122, 204, 210).$

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

In Peter Ansell's old [website](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506190741/https://sites.google.com/site/sevensixthpowers/), he has given <strike>three</strike>
***four*** numerical solutions to the equation:

$$a^6+b^6+c^6+d^6+e^6+f^6+g^6=(a+b+c+d+e+f+g)^6=z^6$$

where $(a,b,c,d,e,f,g;z)$ are,

$$(3936,4230,3300,1854,-888,-3187,-4170;\, 5075)\\(3912,3858,2654,3300,-495,-3018,-4884;\, 5327)\\(3546,7209,9194,2046,108,-2712,-8982;\, 10409)\\
(20, 4260, 5778, 11157, 12414, - 7278, - 11994;\, 14357)$$

Comment: Thank you! Could you give me a reference?

Comment: Arriving at a formula & finding new numerical solutions from the above answer for degree six could be difficult. It was possible for degree four. For degree three there is a solution given by Ramanujan for (2a,2b,2c)^3=(a+b+c)^3 where [2a=6x^2+10xy-10y^2),2b=(8x^2-8xy+12y^2),2c=(10x^2-10xy-6y^2)]. For y=0 we get (6,8,10)^3=(3+4+5)^3=(12)^3

Comment: Cont'd: I noticed that there is parametrization for degree two. (a^2+b^2+c^2)=(a-b+c)^2 where (a,b,c)=(3p,3q,pq) & p=(3k-2) & q=(3k-5) & for k=2, we get (a,b,c)=(12,4,-3). Also, for degree five there is an interesting numerical solution:  (a,b,c,d,e)^5=(4(a-b)+d+e+f)^5=(w)^5 where (a,b,c,d,e,w)=(100,80,57,43,7,107)

Comment: @user967210 See http://euler.free.fr/database.txt and search for the term "Ansell".