# On Sixth Powers $x_1^6+x_2^6+x_3^6+\dots+x_7^6 = z^6$ revisited

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, computational-mathematics

While answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4746879/4781), I decided to revisit the equation,

$$x_1^6+x_2^6+x_3^6+\dots+x_7^6 = z^6$$

which I asked about in [an old post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/392857/4781) and, with today's faster computers, might yield some new insights. Primitive solutions to the equation,

$$x_1^k+x_2^k+x_3^k+\dots+x_{k+1}^k = z^k$$

**where k+1 is a prime *p*** come in two kinds: 1st, $z$ is integrally divisible by $p$, or 2nd, it is not. The 1st kind has smaller solutions than the 2nd kind, but it is the latter we are interested in since there is a possibility one of its terms is $x_i=0$.

---

**I. 4th powers:** $(k+1 = 5)$

$$2^4 + 2^4 + 3^4 + 4^4 + 4^4 = 5^4$$
$$10^4 + 10^4 + 10^4 + 17^4 + 30^4 = 31^4 = z_1^4$$
$$\;\color{red}{0^4} + 30^4 + 120^4 + 272^4 + 315^4 = 353^4 = z_2^4$$

Note that for the 2nd kind, then $z_2=353$ is ***more than 10x*** the smaller solution $z_1=31$ (which is prime). This may give us a rough idea of what to expect for 6th powers.

---

**II. 6th powers:** $(k+1 = 7)$

$$74^6 + 234^6 + 402^6 + 474^6 + 702^6 + 894^6 + 1077^6 = 1141^6 =(7\times163)^6$$
$$42^6(195^6 + 260^6 + 440^6 + 506^6 + 580^6) + 19229^6 + 33354^6 = 34781^6$$
$$\color{red}{0^6}+x_1^6+x_2^6+x_3^6+x_4^6+x_5^6+x_6^6 = z_2^6$$

Based on 4th powers, we could assume that $z_2$ is ***more than 14x*** the smaller solution $z_1=34781$ (which is also prime), or roughly $z_2 > 480000$. In fact, according to a 2002 paper, Meyrignac claims no solutions with $z_2 < 730000$.

**Edit**: I just noticed that $730000/34781 \approx 20.99$, so it seems $z_2$ is ***more than 21x*** the smaller solution $z_1$. If the trend continues, it does not bode well for $10$th powers.

---

**III. Tables for 6th powers**

In Meyrignac's site http://euler.free.fr/database.txt, there are exactly $100+78=178$ ***known*** solutions to the equation (6,1,7) with $z<412000$. We are interested in the $78$ solutions of the **2nd kind**. Statistics are,

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Range name}&\text{Range of z}&\text{Solutions}&\text{Year}\\
\hline
R_1& \qquad 1-100000& 12 &2000\\
\hline
R_2& 100001-200000& 17&2000\\
\hline
R_3& 200001-300000& 32&2006-2008\\
\hline
R_{4a}& 300001-350000& 16&2008-2012\\
\hline
R_{4b}& 350001-400000& 0&\text{(gap)}\\
\hline
R_5& 400001-500000& 1&2010\\
\hline
\text{Total}& \;\qquad 1-500000 &78& 2000-2012^{\large{*}}\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Large $z$ with $z<350000$ were found mostly by Rolan Christofferson between 2006-2012. But recently in **2021**, Ian Stopher found an additional solution in that range, namely $z=319799$. So obviously it was **not** an exhaustive search.

---

**IV. Questions**

Assume solutions of the **2nd kind**. The first twelve known are $R_1$ = (34781, 38191, 39779, 54347, 59819, 63631, 66029, 67681, 70513, 78919, 89797, 97081).

1. Do we now have the computing power to do an exhaustive search for $z<200000$? (It is expected $R_1 = 12,\,R_2 = 19$ will be sparse, but they seem *too* sparse compared to $R_3= 32$. And $R_1$ doesn't seem to be evenly spread with nothing for 40000-50000.)
2. Or power even for $z<400000$? Since $R_{4a} = 16$, then $R_{4b}$ may be similar and the total could be $R_4 > (R_3 = 32)$.

Comment: Updates of 2009 are apparently available in https://oeis.org/A132410 .

Comment: @R.J.Mathar By coincidence, somebody also emailed me about this sequence. This old update covers only $z<15000$ and are ALL $z = 7m$ (I tested them all). As Ansell labels the sequence as "smallest primitive solutions", presumably he did an exhaustive search but stopped at $z=15000$. The smallest $z\neq 7m$ is currently $z=34781$, though I don't know if Meyrignac did an exhaustive search, since there are large gaps in the data from $15000-35000$.

Comment: For $8$th powers, there is one (8,1,8) found by Scott Chase in 2000 and its $z_2 = 1409$ (which is prime) is relatively small, $$90^8 + 223^8 + 478^8 + 524^8 + 748^8 + 1088^8 + 1190^8 + 1324^8=1409^8$$ simply because $k+1 = 9$ is not prime and its congruence constraints are different. However, no (8,1,9) has been found yet which is strange since $z_1$ is normally smaller.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would help with a computer search for solutions of (6,1,7) but it's worth noting that a necessary condition for a solution is: $$x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+\dots+x_7^2-z^2\equiv 0 \pmod{60}$$  This is because $x^6-x^2=(x^2-1)x^2(x^2+1)$ which must be divisible by $3$, $4$ and $5$ (the last because squares are congruent to $0$ or $\pm1$ to mod $5$).

Comment: @AdamBailey Ok, noted. Going higher to (8,1,9) in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4754224/4781), it turns out there are _two_ solutions (with Chase's result the special case of a zero term). However, _both_ solutions obey the congruence $$x_9 + z \equiv 0\,\text{mod 32}$$ where $z$ is signed. Coincidence, or a valid congruence for (8,1,9)?